# Creating ArcGIS toolbox that gives minimum number of points that can observe road

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, viewshed, visibility

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

```
for value in fcVertexList:
    x = arcpy.sa.Viewshed(in_raster=L_34_067_BD_dted2_tif_img, in_observer_features=value)
    
        
    #Raster Calculator
    Visibi_raster =  (Visibil_Value_==1) & ( x == 1)
    if Visibi_raster.maximum == 0:
        obs_posibil = []
        print(type(Visibil_Value_), "a intrat in if pentru punctul final")
        r=arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(Visibil_Value_)
        rasHeight_copy = rasHeight
        for j in r:
            rasHeight_copy -= 1
            search = numpy.where(j == 1)
            for var in search[0]:
                obs_posibil.append((var, rasHeight_copy))
        #Save a point       
        pt = arcpy.Point(inRasterCoordX[obs_posibil[0][1]][obs_posibil[0][0]],inRasterCoordY[obs_posibil[0][1]][obs_posibil[0][0]])
        ptGeom =  arcpy.PointGeometry(pt, sr)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(ptGeom,"centru{0}".format(str(i)))
        i+=1

        Visibil_Value_ = x
    else:
        Visibil_Value_ = Visibi_raster
```

This is a part of code. In fcVertexList are all the road's vertices.

Practically, it makes a viewshed analysis to each pixel of DEM that over which the road passes and overlaps the resulting rasters to see which areas have visibility over a section of road.

The problem is that this algorithm is not efficient because it must to calculate the viewshed to each pixel again and again, until the overlap raster is 0, I need the formula behind the viewshed to can calculate the viewshed just for the already overlap zone.

If you can help me to understand how arcpy.sa.viewshed work; i already read the arcpy help, but i need the algorithm behind the function to understand or a function that can calculate the visibility between two points.